# Access Photos.sqlite in iOS to retrieve photo meta data

Tags: ios, iphone, sqlite, ios7

I'm struggling to find information about how to access the `Photos.sqlite` database. The following information are missing:

1. Is it possible to access the `Photos.sqlite` database from my own application/framework?
2. If `Yes`, where can I find documentation about accessing the `Photos.sqlite` db?
3. Is it possible to retrieve meta data from photos in the database? I would like to get the following meta data

   - Timestamp of photo
   - GPS information `Latitude` and `Longitude`

Assuming that there is **NO** chance to get the information out of the `Photos.sqlite` db. What's the best way to deal with photo meta data from the device photo library?

The following `search criteria` are relevant for me:

- Retrieve photos by date
- Retrieve photos by `CLLocationCoordinates`

**Traversing all the photos in a for-loop every call is definitely too slow!!!**

I think that dealing with photo libraries with 1000+ photos leaves me no choice as creating my own database. Is that right? If **YES**, does someone could give me a suggestion how the database model should look like?

Answer (score 0):

To access photos from the device photo library, you don't access the `sqlite` database directly, but instead use the `AssetsLibrary` framework provided by Apple to retrieve the images and their associated metadata. See here for more information: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AssetsLibrary/Reference/ALAssetsLibrary_Class/Reference/Reference.html